# Many external "On-Link" IPv4 addresses shown as Persistent routes in Windows

Tags: windows, ip, route

When I run `route print` on my "normal" Windows 10 Pro machine, the "Persistent Routes" section lists 136 (!) Network addresses with a /32 mask, and "On-link" as the Gateway.

Many of the IP addresses seem to belong to Microsoft or Akamai, but there are also many others.

Where do all these routes come from? What is their purpose? Can I delete them all?

Here is a shortened version of my `route print` output:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 12...48 0f cf 51 50 6b ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I218-LM
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 17...00 15 5d 10 76 b6 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
 32...00 15 5d 82 1b 63 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.88     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
[ ... etc. as usual ... ]
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      23.99.10.11  255.255.255.255         On-link        1
      23.102.21.4  255.255.255.255         On-link        1
    23.212.108.87  255.255.255.255         On-link        1
    23.212.108.95  255.255.255.255         On-link        1
[ ... many more ...]
   212.30.134.205  255.255.255.255         On-link        1
   216.38.172.128  255.255.255.255         On-link        1
   216.58.198.230  255.255.255.255         On-link        1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 12    281 ::/0                     fe80::125a:f7ff:fe53:1d07
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
[ ... etc. ... ]
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

And in case it's useful (or just for the curious), here is an excerpt of the hostnames or whois "NetName" of these IP addresses:

```bash
cat win10-pers-routes.txt \
| while read ip; do h=$(host $ip) || h=$(whois $ip | grep -i NetName:); printf "%-15s  %s\n" "$ip" "$h"; done
```

```
23.102.21.4      NetName:        MSFT
23.212.108.87    87.108.212.23.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer a23-212-108-87.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.
23.212.108.95    95.108.212.23.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer a23-212-108-95.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.
...
37.252.163.4     netname:        EUADNEXUS-AMS1-IB-1
...
64.4.6.100       NetName:        MICROSOFT
...
65.39.117.230    NetName:        PINPOINT-PNPT
65.52.100.7      7.100.52.65.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer df.telemetry.microsoft.com.
...
65.55.39.10      10.39.55.65.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer xnacreators.net.
...
65.55.252.190    NetName:        MICROSOFT-1BLK
68.67.152.94     NetName:        APPNE-NET1
68.67.153.87     87.153.67.68.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer lbip767081.nym2.adnexus.net.
...
68.67.152.172    NetName:        APPNE-NET1
68.232.34.200    NetName:        EDGECAST-NETBLK-04
82.199.80.143    netname:        TC-MEDIAMIND
93.184.215.200   netname:        EDGECAST-NETBLK-03
94.245.121.179   179.121.245.94.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer db3aqu.atdmt.com.
...
98.124.243.41    NetName:        ENOM-BLOCK-2
111.221.29.177   netname:        Microsoft
...
131.107.255.255  255.255.107.131.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer dns.msftncsi.com.
131.253.40.37    NetName:        MICROSOFT
...
157.55.129.21    NetName:        MSFT-GFS
...
168.61.24.141    NetName:        MICROSOFT
168.62.187.13    NetName:        MICROSOFT
168.63.108.233   NetName:        MICROSOFT
173.252.88.160   NetName:        FACEBOOK-INC
191.232.80.58    
191.232.80.60    
191.232.80.62    
191.232.139.253  
191.232.139.254  
191.232.140.76   
191.237.208.126  
192.229.233.249  NetName:        EDGECAST-NETBLK-08
207.46.101.29    NetName:        MICROSOFT-GLOBAL-NET
...
212.30.134.204   netname:        Akamai-in-MTS-node
216.38.172.128   NetName:        WIRE-TV
216.58.198.230   230.198.58.216.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer lhr26s04-in-f6.1e100.net.
230.198.58.216.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer lhr26s04-in-f230.1e100.net.
230.198.58.216.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer lhr44s02-in-f6.1e100.net.
```

Comment: Is there a VPN client?

Comment: @GregAskew: No, no VPN on this machine.